# Fish from local chip shops smells fishy, but not from one shop?

Tags: fish, smell, chips

As per the title, we have tried fish and chips from several local fish and chip shops, and whenever we get in the car to drive home with them we instantly smell the fish.

However a new fish and chip shop opened recently, and the fish has no smell at all. Haddock or Cod it doesn't matter.

The fish from the none smelly shop possibly seems a little softer too.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Fresher fish? Welcome to the site!

Comment: Apart from the lack of smell, what's it taste like?

Comment: Probably its not fish such as Cod or Haddock.
Many shop s in UK are fraudulent my using taste likey cheaper fish.
Some shops are being fined for fish fraud crime.

Answer (score 4):

very very fresh fish won't smell fishy, and the fishy smell comes from proteins breaking down with age. Texture also degrades and becomes softer with fish that isn't fresh, so what you're describing fits perfectly with this new shop just serving fresher fish.

Comment: Or, if they change their frying oil more often than the others, those odors don't accumulate and get passed on as much, but more probably the freshness.

Comment: Hmmm, the problem I have is that the fish from the new shop that doesn't smell is the softer fish, and this is the opposite of the smelly, older fish being softer.

I wonder if they could be using older fish, but marinading it in something to get rid of the smell?

Anyway, I appreciate you all taking the time to answer, I'll just have to ask the guy next time I go in and see what he has to say.

I'll report back!

Comment: that's very interesting, and I can't think of anything that would get rid of the fishy smell without making the fish firmer (acids) and also not significantly flavor the fish.

Comment: @bigsandwich   I associate that smell with fish that is less than sea-fresh.  I also associate fishy smell with ammonia, a sure sign that the fish should be served to the cat! My friends from France & Italy often remark that fishmongers in the UK have a "fishy" smell, something rarely encountered on the continent. A soft texture may also indicate that the fish has been frozen and that it hasn't been allowed to thaw in a timely way. I came across this with a Dover Sole in a famous French restaurant here in Southeast Asia. It was probably frozen rather than chilled (as claimed) in transit